# slim php to jquery post fail not called

Tags: jquery, slim

I've made an ajax request with jquery to a slim app everything is working great except for error response handling in jquery.

JQuery code

```
function userSignup(mail,password,callback){
    $.post(domain+"user/signup",{mail:mail,password:password})
    .done(function(data){
        callback(data);// this works fine no problem here
    })
    .fail(function(data){
        console.log("My message error that never show up");
    });
}
```

The php route

```
$app->post('/user/signup', function($request,$response,$args){
    global $errors;

    $params=$request->getParsedBody();
    $controllerResponse=userSignup($params["mail"],$params["password"]);

    if(isset($controllerResponse["errorCode"])){
        //the code here returns exactly what I want : a 409 error header with a json containing the error message
        return $response->withJSON(
            ["message"=>$errors[$controllerResponse["errorCode"]]["message"]],
            $errors[$controllerResponse["errorCode"]]["response header"]);
    }

    return $response->withStatus(201);
});
```

network response :
[error console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AegYq.png)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5bGg.png)

the console log in fail in not showing up so it's not triggered, but that's an error header doesn't it should be called?

Hope I made it clear for you to understand

Comment: Are you saying that the request returning a 409 is executing the done logic and not the fail logic?

Comment: Then just add the error code: `return $response->withStatus(409)->withJSON->...` to the response object.